# Print failed row PreparedStatement addBatch

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using PreparedStatement addBatch.

How should I handle the scenario like when a row fails to insert ?

For example, suppose out of 1000 rows to be inserted, the 100th row failed to insert and the program ends abruptly without inserting the remaining rows (i.e. from 100th row to 1000th row).

I would like to print the fail row so I will be able to check the issue.

Comment: If the "program ends abruptly" that sounds like it's an exception. Have you tried just catching the exception?

Comment: yes but I would like the last sql query it try to execute not the reason why it fail

Comment: I use mssql so how should I do it with mssql driver

Comment: Yes, you've tried catching the exception? If so, what exception was it, and did you try continuing after catching the exception? (Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Just put your code inside a try/catch block and catch first BatchUpdateException and after Exception. You should likely get the first and in that case just check the number of items in the returned array, calling the getUpdateCounts() on the exception object, otherwise tell us what kind of exception you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard behaviour for the `ExecuteBatch` method as to error handling and return value, it depends the DBMS and JDBC driver you use.
For example the Oracle driver returns in the `BatchUpdateException` an array with an element for each record that was successful. The indices of the array line up with the indices of the the batches added to the statement, which means that the biggest array index indicates the last batch record that was successfully inserted.
But this could not be valid for your specific DMBS/driver combination, so the only way to check it is to use debugger, simulate the error, set a breakpoint at the exception catching code and look at the exception object.